# Create regex based on variables

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, accumulo

I am having a bit of trouble creating a regex for a database query I am doing. Im currently using an Accumulo database (which doesn't matter @ this point). In Accumulo a row looks like:

`rowid    columnfamily    :    columnqualifier    [ ]    value`

and you are allowed to pattern match on each of the four with an iterator. So where I am having trouble is trying to come up with a pattern to match the `rowid`. An entire row looks like this

`2beab7b3-0792-4347-a63b-3e2f3c6b048d.4ce7be2a-fb2e-4694-94db-877a0ed3e68b.edd1918d-9ddc-4597-891a-d12c8c7be602.1445442700588 transaction:occurrences []    @\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`

Where just the `rowid` I am trying to match looks like:

`2beab7b3-0792-4347-a63b-3e2f3c6b048d.4ce7be2a-fb2e-4694-94db-877a0ed3e68b.edd1918d-9ddc-4597-891a-d12c8c7be602.1445442700588`

This is a unique key I created using 3 other keys (from 3 objects) and a timestamp which are all separated by `.`. So basically we have this:

```
2beab7b3-0792-4347-a63b-3e2f3c6b048d    //key 1 for the method below
4ce7be2a-fb2e-4694-94db-877a0ed3e68b    //dont care about this key
edd1918d-9ddc-4597-891a-d12c8c7be602    //key 3 for the method below
1445442700588                           //dont care about the timestamp
```

The method I am working with will be something like this:

```
public blah getBlah(String key1, String key3){
    //do regex stuff
}
```

Where `key1` is the first section of the greater key (shown above) and `key3` is the third part of the greater key (also shown above).

So it all boils down to the fact that I will know 2 parts of a four part compound key that will always be in the same form, and I need to create a regex or pattern matcher to find out when the first and third part of the key match the inputs of the method `getBlah()`.

**EDIT**

The catch in Accumulo (for this case at least) is that I am building the regex *for* the query basically. So when the method `getBlah(String k1, String k2)` is called, I won't have queried the database yet so I won't know the whole key or even what the row looks like. The query is basically like a select statement in this case. So it will go through the entire table and look @ `rowid`'s where this pattern happens to match, and then pull down all of the matches. So I need to be able to use this method to dynamically match the pattern of `rowid`s without knowing them before hand.

So all `rowid`s will always be in the form of `xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx` and the keys that are passed into the method will always represent the first and third set of x's.

Comment: Great explanation about the background of your question, but about the regex ... what have you tried? And why do you want to create a regexp in the first place, why don't you just split on the '.' and take the first and the third element of the result? (A String.split pattern is also a regex, so for you that would be "\\.")

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. I updated the op probably while you were typing a response to explain that you can't do something like a split. You don't know the whole key before you go into the method. I am trying to build a regex depending on what is passed in. In turn, the Accumulo query I am building kind of works like a `select from table where blah = whatever`. Depending on the regex, the results will only be pulled down if they match the pattern. I don't want to have to pull everything down, then sort through it, or worse make multiple queries.

Comment: If I may ask what is the purpose of the getBlah function? If it's for retrieving certain records in frequent use then using regex is enormously expensive, because the sheer number of rows you have to scan. In that case consider using secondary (and perhaps tertiary) index. If that function seldomly used and you have access to the clusters consider using custom iterator extending filter iterator. Otherwise you just have to scan and filter the result

Answer (score 0):

how about this, and please correct me if i'm wrong

```
key1\..*\.key3
```

or

```
\\.([a-z0-9-])*\\." + k2 + "\\.[0-9]*
```

if you have k2 as a variable

if you try to match this pattern on the rowId column, i think this should give you the correct row

Comment: This does not work. I'm thinking it has to be more like `k1 + "(\\.)([a-z0-9-]*)(\\.)" + k2`

Comment: dont you mean k3 at the end?

Comment: apart from that you have got it

Comment: so yeah, basically key1 followed by a . followed by any number of any chars followed by . followed by key3 :)

Comment: This was the winning solution `\\.([a-z0-9-])*\\." + k2 + "\\.[0-9]*` IF you update your answer I'll select it (because as is didn't work :p )

Comment: done. i thought k1 and k3 were your inputs. anyway, glad you were able to resolve

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct regex from above you could enhance your query performance by restricting your scan range to `key1`. So Accumulo doesn't have to do a full table scan.

```
Range myScanRange = Range.prefix(key1);
myScanner.setRange(myScanRange);
```

see: [Range documentaion](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/data/Range.html#prefix(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text))